# Docker deploy zookeeper cluster

Tags: docker

Why don't you need to expose ports 2888 and 3888 under ports when deploying a zookeeper cluster using docker-compose?

```yaml
services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/:

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

Containers in the same network can connect to each other without the need to expose ports.